# Remove leading X from attribute node and text

Tags: xslt

I'm trying without much luck to simply remove a single character "X" from an attribute.

I have as input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

<Employee>

<Information>
<ID PriorValue="">429</ID>
<Code PriorValue="X55">X5005</Code>
</Information>

</Employee>

<Employee>

<Information>
<ID PriorValue="">950</ID>
<Code PriorValue="X57">X5007</Code>
</Information>

</Employee>

</root>
```

I'm trying to remove the capital X from Prior_Value attribute and from Code to look like:

```
<root>

<Employee>

<Information>
<ID PriorValue="">429</ID>
<Code PriorValue="55">5005</Code>
</Information>

</Employee>

<Employee>

<Information>
<ID PriorValue="">950</ID>
<Code PriorValue="57">5007</Code>
</Information>

</Employee>

</root>
```

This seems to work but not sure it is the ideal approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 version="1.0" xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Information/Code">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
<xsl:attribute name="PriorValue">
<xsl:value-of select="translate(@PriorValue,'X','')"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Code,'X','')"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've been primarily tasked with transforming xml data sets into fixed width or csv formats using for-each construct.  But now am being asked to do global search and replace operations and rearranging xpaths for huge complex xml files. Methods for applying templates to an entire xml file making subtle changes here and there is new for me.

Comment: This is easily done with an identity transform plus a template to match `@PriorityValue` and conditionally replace its value.  Why don't you try it and add the attempt and any particular problem you encounter to your question if you have trouble?  [**Here's a similar Q/A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32954516/290085) to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your example kj but I don't want to remove X from every PriorValue attribute. Just the one of Code.

Comment: Fine, so match `Code/@PriorityValue`.  Point remains that you should show an attempt; otherwise, you risk having your question closed as too broad.  I tried to get you started by providing an example of how to use the identity transformation.  You should be able to make progress from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there with dropping the `X` from the values. One small change that you need to make in the `Information/Code` template is to change the below line

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Code,'X','')"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'X','')"/>
```

Since the current context is already `Code`, XSLT will try to check for `Code/Code` for replacing the value which is not what is required. The change is to look for `.` i.e. current node's value instead of `Code`. The updated template should look like

```
<xsl:template match="Information/Code">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:attribute name="PriorValue">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(@PriorValue,'X','')" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'X','')" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Output

```
<root>
    <Employee>
        <Information>
            <ID PriorValue="">429</ID>
            <Code PriorValue="55">5005</Code>
        </Information>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Information>
            <ID PriorValue="">950</ID>
            <Code PriorValue="57">5007</Code>
        </Information>
    </Employee>
</root>
```

Comment: Apologies for this belated thanks, Aniket. (Thought I would get an email when someone responded.) Thanks again for the help. I made the change as you suggest.

Comment: @Bryant Glad to be of help. If the answer has worked for you, could you please accept the answer. [How to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)